# 'cdecl attribute ignored error' and how to solve this error?

Tags: cdecl

i'm using gcc on ubuntu 20.04 ,gcc version 9.4.0

i use opensources which is 'xsens-old' and then i typed cmake..
and then i got below error result
how to solve this problem?? what does that mean 'attribute ignore' in this situations?

'error result'

cmtdef.h:1134:114: error: ‘cdecl’ attribute ignored [-Werror=attributes]
1134 |  instance, int32_t callbackType, void* param, void* userParam);

'code'

typedef void (__cdecl * CmtCallbackFunction)(int32_t instance, int32_t callbackType, void* param, void* userParam);